# page error when writeImage()

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have script to resize my photo with [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php) and then save.
Here is code to make thumbnail with `thiumbnailImage();`

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
  $image = new Imagick('test.jpg');
  $image->thumbnailImage(600, 0);
  echo $image;
?>
```

Exmaple -> [Resize example just thumbnailImage();](http://dugg.cz/test.php).

This works.
But when i want to save it with `writeImage();`.

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
  $image = new Imagick('test.jpg');
  $image->readImage('test.jpg');
  $image->thumbnailImage(600, 0);
  $image->writeImage('test_resized.jpg');
?>
```

It display server error. Example -> [Example resize with writeImage();](http://dugg.cz/test2.php)

Comment: Do you have an example that save image file, not outputting to browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you probably don't have write permission to that directory.. Set permission(CHMOD) to 777.

Comment: Happy to help! You should accept any answer if you think it helped ;). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. I didn't have permission to writeImage();

Answer (score 1):

To debug the error, try this code:

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  // header('Content-type: image/jpeg');  // note this is commented
  $image = new Imagick('test.jpg');
  $image->readImage('test.jpg');
  $image->thumbnailImage(600, 0);
  $image->writeImage('test_resized.jpg');
?>
```

The reason for commenting out the `header` call is so that the browser doesn't try to display the page as an image and prevent you from viewing source or seeing error messages.

Comment: Thanks, it was problem on server with permission, it's working now